# How to get next item in mysql order by createdAt

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

My frontend app can list of my items order by `createdAt` (for sure by calling API):

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY createdAt
```

Output is for example:

```
id: myIdAAA
id: myIdEEE
id: myIdPPP
id: myIdRRR
```

Id of each item is UUID (there in example just `myId*`).

I can open detail of item by url `/item/detail/myIdPPP` and on this detail I have `GO TO NEXT` item.

The problem is, that I don`t know how to create SQL query to select next item like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items AFTER myIdEEE ORDER BY createdAt
```

Should return `myIdPPP`.

```
SELECT * FROM items AFTER myIdPPP ORDER BY createdAt
```

Should return `myIdRRR`.

It is possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i
WHERE i.createdAt > (SELECT i2.createdAt FROM items i2 WHERE i2.id = ?)
ORDER BY i.createdAt DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder for the item of interest.  This returns the next time timewise in the table -- assuming there are no duplicates.

Note:  If you really want a unique value for getting the "next" item, then use an auto-incremented column.  This is guaranteed to be unique, even if you insert multiple items at the same time.